# Aptana 3 - Code completion not showing all browsers

Tags: css, autocomplete, aptana

My Aptana 3's code completion is not showing all browsers for keyword browser compatibility.

In various tutorials, I saw Aptana can show icons for Chrome, Firefox, IE, Opera and then CSS Core in the pop-up code completion drop down. I only see Firefox and IE.

I have all browsers installed and available in Aptana and they do show up under the 'Green Play Button' drop down.

How do I get to see all browser compatibility for keywords?

Answer (score 1):

In "Aptana Menu Window/preferences/aptana/editors" you can see a browsers to use in code assist.